# Styling attribute nested within an id a class and another attribute

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```css
html body .section1 #red-text p {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link ref="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="section1">
            <div id="red-text">
                <p>This text should be red.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <p>This text should be left alone.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to change the color of the "This text should be red" text using CSS.  I've attempted the following CSS code to no avail:

```
html body .section1 #red-text p {
    color: red;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: id elements are unique, so there is no reason to add prefixes: just `#red-text p { ... }` is enough to target all paragraphs inside that div. However, using id attributes for styling is basically doing HTML markup wrong: make that id a class (which is the attribute intended for applying styles encoded in stylesheets), and use `.red-text p { ... }` in your stylesheet instead. Things will be a lot cleaner that way.

Comment: your code is fine like demonstrated in the snippet I created. Clear your cache or check the file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by the others above, the code is technically fine, however you'd be wise to practice using classes instead of IDs when styling! Also, as Mike says, IDs are unique so no need for the prefixes.

That said, you haven't marked as solved so here's probably what the code should look like to be more effective.

```
`<html>
    <head>
        <link ref="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="section1">
            <div id="inner-section">
                <p class="red-text">This text should be red.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>This text should be left alone.</p>
    </body>
</html>`
```

And then you can simplify the CSS because any other text you need to be red, can just be the same class! so:

```
`.red-text {
    color: red;
}`
```

Or if you want just to style just the red text in that div:

```
`#inner-section.red-text {
    color: red;
}`
```